# ¿Leer caracters con scanf,¿con getchar() contra sin getchar() con "\n%c"?

Tags: c, while, entrada, scanf

Las tres programas hacen la misma tarea - cifrar con el cifrado de César.

Codigo uno:

```
 puts("Cifrar las cinco letras que introduzca el usuario. Introduce un carácter:");
 char i, ii, iii, iv, v;
 scanf("%c", &i);
 getchar();
 puts("Introduce un carácter:");
 scanf("%c", &ii);
 getchar();
 puts("Introduce un carácter:");
 scanf("%c", &iii);
 getchar();
 puts("Introduce un carácter:");
 scanf("%c", &iv);
 getchar();
 puts("Introduce el último carácter:");
 scanf("%c", &v);
 
 
 printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n", i+3, ii+3, iii+3, iv+3, v+3);
```

Codigo dos:

```
 puts("Cifrar las cinco letras que introduzca el usuario. Introduce un carácter:");
 char i, ii, iii, iv, v;
 scanf("%c", &i);
 puts("Introduce un carácter:");
 while(getchar()!='\n');
 scanf("%c", &ii);
 puts("Introduce un carácter:");
 while(getchar()!='\n');
 scanf("%c", &iii);
 puts("Introduce un carácter:");
 while(getchar()!='\n');
 scanf("%c", &iv);
 puts("Introduce el último carácter:");
 while(getchar()!='\n');
 scanf("%c", &v);
 
 
 printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n", i+3, ii+3, iii+3, iv+3, v+3);
```

Codigo tres:

```
 
 puts("Cifrar las cinco letras que introduzca el usuario. Introduce un carácter:");
 char i, ii, iii, iv, v;
 scanf("%c", &i);
 puts("Introduce un carácter:");
 scanf("\n%c", &ii);
 puts("Introduce un carácter:");
 scanf("\n%c", &iii);
 puts("Introduce un carácter:");
 scanf("\n%c", &iv);
 puts("Introduce el último carácter:");
 scanf("\n%c", &v);
 
 
 printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n", i+3, ii+3, iii+3, iv+3, v+3);
```

¿Cuál de ellos es más seguro?
Las programas son cortos, el comando `time` de cada uno de ellas me dio `user  0m0.001s sys  0m0.00s` . Suponiendo que fueran a procesar 10000 caracteres, ¿cuál de ellos podría ser más rápido?
Me parece que el segundo es más rapido que codigo uno.

Comment: Pues si por cada linea quieres unicamente un caracter, me inclinaria por la segunda opcion, ya que validas que no queden mas caracteres en la linea. Pero para lo que esta haciendo tu programa, seria mucho mejor usar un `char[]` y leer con `scanf("%s", ...)` o `fgets`.

Comment: @Pablochaches Si leo todos characteres de la palabra con fgets, como luego cifrar?

Comment: Usas un `for` sumandole 3 a todos los caracteres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Cuál de ellos es más seguro?

Las 3 opciones son a grandes rasgos igual de seguros o inseguros. El mayor problema de estos ejemplos es su escasa utilidad real.

Por un lado estás imponiendo una entrada de tamaño fijo, cuando en la mayoría de los casos la entrada tendrá un tamaño variable.

Por otro no estás validando los caracteres, luego el programa te admitiría perfectamente un tabulador, un espacio o cualquier otra cosa (incluso un salto de línea -> prueba a meter dos saltos de línea seguidos)

Crear una lectura a prueba de balas puede ser complicado, en tu caso se podría intentar con algo así:

```
int getChar(char * c)
{
    do
    {
        *c = getchar();
        if (*c == EOF) return 0;
    } while ((*c < 'A') || (*c > 'Z' && *c < 'a') || (*c > 'z'));

    return 1;
}
```

Con esto la lectura filtraría todo aquello que no sean caracteres alfabéticos.

Sin embargo, los problemas de tu aplicación no terminan ahí. Así, tu programa obtendrá respuestas erróneas en los casos límite

- Si tu programa esta inicialmente pensado para cifrar los caracteres en el rango A-Z, ¿qué pasa si se introduce una `Z`? Según la tabla ASCII saldrá `]` cuando lo esperable en el cifrado césar sería `C`
- Si es aceptable que tu programa acepte también caracteres especiales (paréntesis, comas, puntos, corchetes, ...) entonces seguirás teniendo salidas erróneas en otros caracteres. Así `|`, `}` y `~` tendrán como resultado caracteres no imprimibles

Estas situaciones pueden imposibilitar el descifrado de la secuencia cifrada.

En la vida real lo esperable es que el tamaño del mensaje fuese variable y eso es algo irrealizable con tu código. Sin embargo, al usar bucles la situación cambia enormemente:

```
puts("Introduce el texto a cifrar");
char c;
while (getChar(&c))
{
    c += 3;
    putchar(c);
}
```

Y, comprobando casos límite:

```
puts("Introduce el texto a cifrar");
char c;
while (getChar(&c))
{
    c += 3;
    if (c > 'Z' && c < 'a')
        c -= ('Z' - 'A');
    else if (c > 'z')
        c -= ('z' - 'a');
    putchar(c);
}
```

> ¿cuál de ellos podría ser más rápido?

Salvo que tengas que diseñar un sistema de cifrado con una demanda altísima yo no me preocuparía por el rendimiento. Primero aprende los fundamentos de programación y algoritmia y luego, cuando ya tengas soltura, aprende formas de mejorar el rendimiento