# Problema con un programa en c

Tags: c

soy nuevo programando y necesito ayuda con un programa que tengo como practica de la universidad, ya que la verdad se me dificulta un poco, pero me aparecen varios errores que la verdad no tengo ni idea de como resolver.
El enunciado dice lo siguiente:

Un zoológico desea guardar los datos de los pandas y saber si el panda puede o no tener bebes mediante un mensaje, Además se pretende tener almacenado solamente los nombres y edades de las pandas que pueden dar a luz y visualizar estos registros al final. Para ello se pretende crear una estructura con los siguientes campos: nombre, peso, año de nacimiento, sexo. Debe además crear una función para leer los datos de la estructura.

Uno de los errores dice:[Error] 'panditas' was not declared in this scope, en la linea N.28
y también [Error] no match for 'operator<' in 'contador < panda[100]', en la linea N.49

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<stdlib.h>
            #include<string.h>
            #include <ctype.h>
            #define N 100
            
            typedef struct {
                char nombre[50];
                float peso;
                int anyonac;
                char sexo;
            }panda;

            //Declare las funciones prototipos a utilizar
            void LeerPanda(panda *p); 
            int EdadPanda(panda p); 
            int TenerBebes(panda p);
    
            int main()
            {
                panda panda[N];
                int puede, contador = 0;
                char resp = 's';
        
                do{
                    printf("\nIngrese los datos del panda\n");
                    //Llamar a la función TenerBebes
                    LeerPanda(&panditas[contador], contador);
            
                    puede = TenerBebes(panda[N]);
                       if (puede==1)
            
                         {
                            printf("\nEste panda esta apta para tener bebes\n\n");
                         }
            
                            else
                        {
                            printf("\nEste panda no está apta para tener bebes\n\n");
                        }                                                                             
                        printf("Desea ingresar otro panda? (s/n) \n");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        resp = tolower(getchar());
            
                            if(resp == 's'){
                                contador==0; //se actualiza el contador de pandas                                    
                                             // para ingresar otro
                            }
                }while (contador < panda[N] && resp=='s');  //mientras el contador sea menor 
                                            //que el tamaño del arreglo y la respuesta sea ‘S’
                return 0;
            
            }
            void LeerPanda(panda *p, int pos)
            {
                char nom;      
                printf("El panda se llama: ");
                gets(nom);      
                p->nombre=(char )malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(nom)+1); 
                      if(p==NULL)      
                      {
                            printf("Insuficiente espacio de memoria\n");
                                 exit(1);
                      }      
                      strcpy(p->nombre,nom);      
                      fflush(stdin);     
                      printf("Su peso es:");      
                      scanf("%f",&p->peso);      
                      fflush(stdin);      
                      printf("Su anyo de nacimiento es:");      
                      scanf("%d",&p->anyonac);      
                      fflush(stdin);      
                      printf("Su sexo es:");      
                      scanf("%c",&p->sexo);      
            }
            
            int EdadPanda(panda p)
            {
                    int edadp;
                    edadp=2021 - p.anyonac;
                        return(edadp);
            }
            int Tenerbebes(panda p)
            {
                    int res, edad;
                    edad = EdadPanda(p);
                   
                    if(edad>=5 && (p.sexo=='f' || p.sexo=='F')) 
                        res=1;     
                    else            
                    res=0;      
                    return(res);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Uno de los errores dice:[Error] 'panditas' was not declared in this scope, en la linea N.28

Eso quiere decir que estas usando una variable sin previamente declarar; estuve bien tu codigo y es asi. Y con **scope** se refiere al area entre los `{}`

> y también [Error] no match for 'operator<' in 'contador < panda[100]', en la linea N.49

Estas comparando un objeto tipo `panda` con un `int`, y aqui no hacemos eso! Deberias tener `while (contador < N)`, recuerda que `N` es tu max de pandas.

En `if (puede == 1)` no hay necesidad de checkear si es 1. En C, si es diferente a 0 (o NULL) te dara `true`.

En `fflush(stdin)` esta descartado y despreciado (`fflush(stdout)` es seguro). Su uso conlleva **Comportamiendo indefinido**. Es decir, no lo uses. Si lo tenes alli debes estar usando `scanf()`, en vez de eso usa `fgets()`. Aca hablo sobre el tema: [¿Leer caracters con scanf,¿con getchar() contra sin getchar() con “\n%c”?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/478544/leer-caracters-con-scanf-con-getchar-contra-sin-getchar-con-nc/479765#479765)

**Psdt:** si suministras mas info como la definicion de tus prototipos, actualizare mi respuesta.

---

Aca las modificaciones que he hecho:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 100

typedef struct
{
    char nombre[50];
    float peso;
    int anyonac;
    char sexo;
} panda;

void LeerPanda(panda *p)
{
    /* Para ser usado for fgets. */
    char buffer[50] = {0};

    printf("El panda se llama: ");
    fgets(p->nombre, sizeof p->nombre, stdin);
    p->nombre[strcspn(p->nombre, "\n")] = 0; /* Cambia '\n' por '\0'. */

    printf("Su peso es:");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%f", &p->peso); /* Parsea el string (lo convierte a float). */
    
    printf("Su anyo de nacimiento es:");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &p->anyonac);
    
    printf("Su sexo es:");
    scanf("%c", &p->sexo);
    getchar(); /* Si querres usar scanf siempre, pon getchar despues de cada uso. */
}

int EdadPanda(panda p)
{
    int edadp; 
    edadp = 2021 - p.anyonac;
    return (edadp);
}

int TenerBebes(panda p)
{
    int res, edad;
    edad = EdadPanda(p);

    if (edad >= 5 && (p.sexo == 'f' || p.sexo == 'F'))
        res = 1;
    else
        res = 0;
    return (res);
}

int main()
{
    panda pandas[N]; /* Es array, hace mas sentido `pandas`. */
    int puede, contador = 0;
    char resp = 's';

    do
    {
        printf("\nIngrese los datos del panda\n");
        //Llamar a la función TenerBebes
        LeerPanda(&pandas[contador]);

        puede = TenerBebes(pandas[contador]);
        if (puede)
            printf("\nEste panda esta apta para tener bebes\n\n");
        else
            printf("\nEste panda no está apta para tener bebes\n\n");
        
        printf("Desea ingresar otro panda? (s/n) \n");
        // fflush(stdin); --> No uses eso!!! <---
        resp = tolower(getchar());
        getchar();

        if (resp == 's')
            contador = 0; //se actualiza el contador de pandas
                           // para ingresar otro
        ++contador;
    } while ((contador < N) && (resp == 's')); //mientras el contador sea menor
                                                  //que el tamaño del arreglo y la respuesta sea ‘S’
    return 0;
}
```

### Resultado:

```c
Ingrese los datos del panda
El panda se llama: Maria
Su peso es:85.9
Su anyo de nacimiento es:2003
Su sexo es:f

Este panda esta apta para tener bebes

Desea ingresar otro panda? (s/n) 
s

Ingrese los datos del panda
El panda se llama: Pedro
Su peso es:96.9
Su anyo de nacimiento es:2002
Su sexo es:m

Este panda no está apta para tener bebes

Desea ingresar otro panda? (s/n) 
n
```

Bien, fijate que en `LeerPanda()` querias usar memoria dinamica sin necesidad. Ya que en tu `struct panda` ya has reservado espacio para ello (`char nombre[50]`) asi que simplemente es escribir alli con `fgets()`, y luego remover el `\n` (en este caso lo hice con `strcspn()`). Lo de `scanf()` y `fflush(stdin)` ya lo he comentado asi que no volvere a hablar de ello.

Sin mas que comentar, espero haberte ayudado.